# How to ignore some words inside string when using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What i'm trying to do is

```
$var = "[h1]This is Just a text, [h1]and this inside it[/h1] This just example[/h1]";
$output = preg_replace("/\[h1\](.*?)\[\/h1]/", "<h1>$1</h1>", $var);
echo $output;
```

Here i want to ignore first `[/h1]` to make the result right, How can i achieve it? Did there is anyway to just get first and last tags?

I don't know what i should do or try, i'm not good enough to try in it,

**Edited**

The output is

```
<h1>This is Just a text, [h1]and this inside it</h1> This just example[/h1]
```

but i expected to get

```
<h1>This is Just a text, <h1>and this inside it</h1> This just example</h1>
```

Comment: Please give sample expected output

Comment: @Emerald I have edited my question.

Comment: Please don't change your question requirements now, I need to change many answers too many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output without using regex, if you simply want to replace the strings `[h1]` for `<h1>` etc.

```
<?php
$var = "[h1]This is Just a text, [h1]and this inside it[/h1] This just example[/h1]";

echo str_replace(['[h1]', '[/h1]'], ['<h1>', '</h1>'], $var);
```

**Result:**

```
<h1>This is Just a text, <h1>and this inside it</h1> This just example</h1>
```

https://3v4l.org/q9a41

Comment: Yes! It will work fine too now with simple str_replace +1

Comment: This work like a charm, could you please explain the code? and what `[ ]` means in str_replace?

Comment: It's the short array syntax. which was added in [PHP5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), you could use `str_replace(array('[h1]', '[/h1]'), array('<h1>', '</h1>'), $var);`

Comment: Oh i got it now, its just a array, i think it was something else like a new way to use str_replace. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own function and then use preg_replace with limit 1 like below:

```
<?php
$var = "<h1>This is Just a text, [h1]and this inside it</h1> This just example[/h1]";

function replace_first($from, $to, $replace){
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';
    return preg_replace($from, $to, $replace, 1);
}

$output = replace_first('[h1]', '<h1>', $var);
$output = replace_first('[/h1]', '</h1>', $output);

// Output (HTML Source Code) will be <h1>This is Just a text, <h1>and this inside it</h1> This just example</h1>
?>
```

*Note: This is the 3rd update but might not work if Question further update.*

Comment: I saw the original question and left it, now it can be done with simple `str_replace` since the OP has changed it ;p. +1 for working though it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes OP changed too many times. Every time I update, question requirement changes, thanks for your understanding :)

Comment: @AmitGupta No i haven't update my question too times, just 1 time when i edit it to add sample for what i want, but when i put my $var = as in the question your code will not work, Thanks a lot for trying to help me, i appreciate it.

Comment: @AmitGupta +1 for your trying and kindness. Thanks.